# Simple analytics onclick event not tracking

Tags: events, google-analytics

I have a very basic google event tracking script set up as a test. When clicking the button it should send an event onclick.

I originally had a more complex script which was intended to send an event as part of a jquery function. Since this didn't work I've reduced it down to as little code as possible to get even a basic trigger working.

I've removed the ID number from the script and replaced it with redacted but it's present in the live script.

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=REDACTED"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'REDACTED');
</script>

<button id="test" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'test', 'test', 'test')">test</button>
```

on click of the button I should see the event appear in the analytics real time tracker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the **gtag** code but you are trying to send an event as if you were using the *universal analytics* code.

Try to send the event with the following syntax:

```
gtag('event', <action>, {
  'event_category': <category>,
  'event_label': <label>,
  'value': <value>
});
```

i.e.:

```
gtag('event', 'test', {
  'event_category' : 'test',
  'event_label' : 'test'
});
```